# Toggle data-value after Ajax success without element ID

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have multiple buttons to toggle status of different projects:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle project_status" data-project-id="1" data-form="project_status" data-value="1"> 
  <button class="btn btn-default active">ACTIVE</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">CLOSED</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle project_status" data-project-id="2" data-form="project_status" data-value="1"> 
  <button class="btn btn-default active">ACTIVE</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">CLOSED</button>
</div>
```

I need to toggle the data-value between 1 and 2 when ajax post success.

I have tried this so far but without any luck:

```
$('.project_status').click(function(){
    var project_id = $(this).attr('data-project-id');
    var project_status_val = $(this).attr('data-value');
    var toggle_status = function(){
        $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('active').toggleClass('btn-primary');
        if (project_status_val == '1'){
            alert(project_status_val);
            $(this).attr('data-value','2');
        } else {
            alert(project_status_val);
            $(this).attr('data-value','1');
        }
        return false;
    };
    var dataString = 'project_id=' + project_id + '&project_status=' + project_status_val;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "post.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: toggle_status
    });
    $('#sidebar-wrapper').load('sidebar.php');
    return false;
});
```

I have got the alert data value correct. I have got the sidebar reload with updated value (only the first click). But I am not able to change the attribute value so that the next click will send the toggled value.

Please help! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` inside the toggle_status method is not your btn. Inside the method the `this` keyword refers to the object the method belongs to. In this case `Window`. As a workaround, I have made a `self` property before the method to store a reference to the selected `$('.project_status')` object. I have updated the code so it will work.

https://jsfiddle.net/05akxvx3/1/

```
$('.project_status').click(function(){
  var self = $(this);
  var project_id = self.attr('data-project-id');
  var project_status_val = self.attr('data-value');
  var toggle_status = function(){
    self.find('.btn').toggleClass('active').toggleClass('btn-primary');
    if (project_status_val == '1'){
        self.attr('data-value','2');
    } else {
        self.attr('data-value','1');
    }
    alert(self.attr('data-value'));
    return false;
  };
  var dataString = 'project_id=' + project_id + '&project_status=' + project_status_val;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: toggle_status
  });
  $('#sidebar-wrapper').load('sidebar.php');
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra dash in your `$(this).attr()` statement.

`$(this).attr('data--value','2');` ought to be:

`$(this).attr('data-value','2');`

Comment: It was a typo. I fixed that ealier